# got an error for js call

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I got some conflicts with WP media library and make me cannot switch to insert from URL when I am trying to insert an image when I am implementing the following js. Console shows me this :Uncaught TypeError: a.is is not a function.

```
    var originalVal = $.fn.val;
    $.fn.val = function(value) {

        //is it a radio button? treat it differently.
        if($(this).is("[type=radio]")) {

            if (typeof value != 'undefined') {

                //setter
                changeRadioButton(this, value);
                return $(this);

            } else {

                //getter
                var textValue = $("input[name=section_home_page_field]").val(getRadioButton(this));
                return getRadioButton(this);

            }

        }
        else {

            //it wasn't a radio button - let's call the default val function.
            if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
                return originalVal.call(this, value);
            } else {
                return originalVal.call(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, here

```
else {

                //it wasn't a radio button - let's call the default val function.
                if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
                    return originalVal.call(this, value);
                } else {
                    return originalVal.call(this);
                }
```

Comment: The error seems to be referring to this line, actually: `if($(this).is("[type=radio]")) {`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but I am sure the error is from the section code section

Comment: Apparently WP has [jQuery prepackaged (I think 1.12.0)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/query?type=enhancement&component=External+Libraries&summary=~jquery&col=id&col=summary&col=type&col=milestone&col=time&order=id)... are you importing a different version by any chance? (granted `.is()` was defined in [1.0](http://api.jquery.com/is/))